# margin-bottom is applied in chrome but not in firefox even after using css-reset in modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

css code

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 55px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 24px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: max-content;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.my-slides {
  width: 100%;
}

.my-slides img {
  width: 100%;
}

.closed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

/* Media queries */

@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .modal-content {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 575px) {
  .modal-content {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
}
```

When I use margin-bottom: 50px, it works in chrome but not in firefox, but if I increase it margin-bottom: 100px, it works in chrome and firefox, but the spacing is uneven. As in chrome it takes more space, while in firefox it takes less space.

here is the link:

https://pfs-r.netlify.app/

Comment: try setting the padding of `.modal` to 0 OR use this padding instead of using margin on the `.modal-content`

Comment: @loicEzt   I used padding 0 to .modal, but didnt work, if I use padding instead of margin in .modal-content, it will increase the white space and I dont want that

Comment: have you tried setting the padding of `.modal` without the margin of `.modal-content` ?

Comment: @ loicEzt I did but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting `top: 55px` on the `modal-content` box, set `margin-top: 55px`. Then even the `position: relative` setting is no longer required.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this css:
Don't replace with existing .modal-content.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .modal-content {
     position: relative;
     top: 55px;
     border-radius: 4px;
     padding: 24px;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     width: 70%;
     max-width: 1000px;
     border: none;
     background-color: #fff;
     height: max-content;
     margin-bottom: 50px;
   }
   }
```